# ¿Como mostrar foto en un ListView desde una base de datos?Asp.net,SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net

Este es el codigo de consulta:

```
protected void btnbuscar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = MEGATRON; Initial Catalog = RentCar; Integrated Security = True");
        try
        {

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Autos WHERE Marca like '" + DropDownListMarcas.SelectedItem.Text + "%'", conn);


            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            da.Fill(dt);

            ListView1.DataSource = dt;
            ListView1.DataBind();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Este es el codigo de guardado:

```
  SqlCommand insert = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Autos(codigo, Marca, Modelo,Año, NoPuertas, TipoCombustible, Tipotransmision, Capacidadasientos, Color, Precioxdia,img1) values(@Codigo, @Marca, @Modelo,@Año,@NoPuertas,@TipoCombustible,@Tipotransmision,@Capacidadasientos,@Color,@Precioxdia,@img1)", conn);
        insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Codigo", txtcodigo.Text);
        insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Marca", idmarca.SelectedItem.Text);
        insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Modelo", DropDownListModelo.Text);
        insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Año", DropDownano.Text);
        insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NoPuertas", NoPuertas.Text);
        insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TipoCombustible", txtCombustible.Text);
        insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tipotransmision", DropDownListtransmision.Text);
        insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Capacidadasientos", txtAsientos.Text);
        insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Color", DropDownListColor.Text);
        insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Precioxdia", txtPrecioxdia.Text);
        insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@img1", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = FileUpload1.FileBytes;
```

Tengo este ListView pero lo de la foto o imagen no me funciona.La foto cuando la guardo en la base de datos la almaceno en un campo VarBinary(MAX).

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" >

                       <ItemTemplate>
                           <div class="hola">
                               <table>

                                            <tr><td>
                                     <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" src='<%#Eval("img1") %>' /></td></tr>
                                    <tr><td><h3><%# Eval("Marca") %></h3></td></tr>
                                    <tr><td><h4><%# Eval("Modelo") %></h4></td></tr>
                                    <tr><td><h4><%# Eval("Color") %></h4></td></tr>
                               </table>
                           </div>
                       </ItemTemplate>
                         </asp:ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Si analizas como implemento el gridview en este ejemplo

[[ASP.NET] GridView – Edición Empleados](http://ltuttini.blogspot.com/2011/05/aspnet-gridview-edicion-empleados.html)

el cual aplica igual para el listview, porque el tema pasa en que deberas crear un handler que devuelva el byte array de la imagen en el Response

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Imagen">
     <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" 
            ImageUrl='<%# Eval("IdEmpleado", "imagen.ashx?id={0}") %>' Width="100px" Height="100px" />
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

entonces analiza como es el `.ashx` que recupera la imagen segun el id o codigo del registro

```
public class HttpImageHandler : IHttpHandler
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {

        byte[] imagenEmpleado = ... //aqui recuperas la imagen de la tabla

        // Arma el contexto que enviara la imagen en el response
        // se usa el nombre del empleado para el nombre del archivo que se envia
        //
        context.Response.Clear();
        context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename={0}", "nombreimagen")); 
        context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpg";


        // Se escribe en el response la imagen asociada al empleado
        //
        context.Response.BinaryWrite(imagenEmpleado);
        context.Response.End();
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return false; }
    }
}
```

en el `web.config` recuerda registrar el handler

```
<httpHandlers>

    <add verb="*" path="*.ashx" type="WebAdminEmpleados.HttpImageHandler"/>
</httpHandlers>
```

asi esa extension resuelve con el codigo donde se implementa

Comment: En esto:     path="*.ashx".Hay que añadir algo?

Comment: Disculpa,pero no guardo fotos en ninguna carpeta.

Comment: Eso estaba claro, por eso indique que debes realizar una consulta a la db para recuperar el byte array de la imagen. Solo registras la extension para que resuelva el ashx

Comment: Amigo,No uso id para traer los datos,sino el nombre de una marca según la que seleccione en un dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Todo me funciona bien,así que dejo lo que tengo.

Aqui el codigo del archivo aspx.cs

```
   protected void btnbuscar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = MEGATRON; Initial Catalog = RentCar; Integrated Security = True");
        try
        {

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Autos WHERE Marca like '" + DropDownListMarcas.SelectedItem.Text + "%'" +
                          "AND Tipo like '" + DropDownListTipo.SelectedItem.Text + "%' ", conn);


            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            da.Fill(dt);

            ListView1.DataSource = dt;
            ListView1.DataBind();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Aqui el codigo del aspx:

```
   <asp:Image ID="imgPhoto" runat="server"
            ImageUrl='<%# "HttpImageHandler.ashx?ImID="+ Eval("Codigo") %>' 
  Height="150px" Width="150px"/>
```

Aqui el codigo del handdler(ashx.cs)

```
 public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string imageid = context.Request.QueryString["ImID"];
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source = MEGATRON; Initial Catalog = RentCar; Integrated Security = True");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select img1 from Autos where Codigo=" + imageid, con);
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        dr.Read();
        context.Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])dr[0]);
        con.Close();
        context.Response.End();


    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```